# Creating angularjs directive for javascript array that turns it into a checkbox list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a javascript array as follows:

`['create', 'delete', 'deleteList', 'fetch', 'fetchAll', 'patch', 'replaceList', 'update']`

I am trying to create an angualrjs directive that takes that array and creates a list of checkboxes that uses these keywords in the array and uses true or false based on whether they are checked or not.

What I did so far is this:

Created the following html:

```
<span ng-repeat="method in option.methods">
    <permission-method method="method"></permission-method>
</span>
```

and the following javascript:

```
'use_strict';

var rcDirectives = angular.module('rcDirectives', []);

rcDirectives.directive('permissionMethod', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // element
        scope: {
            method: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '<label>{{method}} <input type="checkbox" value="{{method}}"><label>'
    };
});
```

Not sure how to continue from here...

EDIT1:
To clearify, let's assume I have that array of strings in a json I call `options`. For example:

```
option = 
{ 
    name: "some name", 
    methods = ['fetch', 'fetchAll']
}
```

Now, when I use this directive, it will create the checkbox list using the `methods` array with only the `fetch` and `fetchAll` checked, and also allow me to change the `methods` by adding or removing items from the array.

**In general** this should work for any array, given a premade list of strings.

**MY SOLUTION:**

So here's how I solved it:

I've created an object instead of array like as follows:

```
{ create : false, 'delete' : false, deleteList : false, fetch : true, fetchAll : true, patch : false, replaceList : false, update : false }
```

And on the directive I used this:

```
rcDirectives.directive('permissionData', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // element
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'permissionData.html',
    };
});
```

This is `permissionData.html` contenct:

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        <label>{{key}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data[key]"> 
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to clarify a bit here. You are sending in a list of strings, but want them to act as bools?

Comment: @KGChristensen I want to take that list of strings, and create a directive that (if needed) create a list of its own based on that string list with lets say key (the string) value (bool).

Comment: @KGChristensen I have made an edit to explain further.

Comment: I think just having them set as key : value booleans would be much easier. `methods= [ 'fetch': true, 'fetchAll': true, 'otherMethod': false`]

Then you can just use `ng-show="method"` to determine whether that method is usable in the DOM. I would need to see more code to give you a real demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION:**

So here's how I solved it:

I've created an object instead of array like as follows:

```
{ create : false, 'delete' : false, deleteList : false, fetch : true, fetchAll : true, patch : false, replaceList : false, update : false }
```

And on the directive I used this:

```
rcDirectives.directive('permissionData', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // element
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'permissionData.html',
    };
});
```

This is `permissionData.html` contenct:

```
<div>
    <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        <label>{{key}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data[key]"> 
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

And this is the usage in the html itself:

```
<permission-data data=data></permission-data>
```